# Why is match slower on dates/datetimes in R version 4.3.2 than version 4.2.2

Tags: r

I have recently upgraded R from version 4.2.2 to 4.3.2 and have noticed that the match function is much slower on the newer version when matching dates and datetimes.

For example the below code run on version 4.2.2 takes 0 seconds:

```
sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string    #"R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)"
tictoc::tic()
datetimes <- seq(as.POSIXct('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), by = 'hour')
match(datetimes[1], datetimes)
tictoc::toc()   #0 sec elapsed
```

Running the same code on 4.3.2 takes nearly 2 seconds

```
sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string    #"R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)"
tictoc::tic()
datetimes <- seq(as.POSIXct('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), by = 'hour')
match(datetimes[1], datetimes)
tictoc::toc()   #1.69 sec elapsed
```

The two datetime objects are identical so the issue appears to be with the match function. Also the speed difference between versions isn't present if matching integers.

Can anyone advise on what is causing the difference and how to speed the code on version 4.3.2. (No requirement to use match)?

Comment: Why don't you time the expressions individually ... ? It is not clear at all that `match` (really `mtfrm`) must be slower.  Anyway, R 4.3.0 came with several nontrivial changes to the datetime machinery and one of those could be responsible; see `news(Version == "4.3.0")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  match = match(datetimes[1], datetimes),
  seq = {s <- seq_along(datetimes) * (datetimes == datetimes[1]); min(s[s>0])}, 
  times = 10 
)
```

On my system, using 4.3.2, this variation is 50x faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
 match 1208.4397 1228.4231 1260.49021 1257.2396 1278.4805 1332.9781    10
   seq    4.5865    4.7607   49.59456   40.8281   85.5263   95.5652    10
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is a great speed improvement. Do you know the answer to the first part of my question: why there is a speed difference between R v4.2.2 and R v.4.3.2?

Comment: Sorry, I do not.